# How to color states in US map in R

Tags: r, plot, mapping

I want to draw a US map with some states have blue color and others have white color

Now, I have the list of names of state:

```
c=c("ILLINOIS", "KANSAS","LOUISIANA","MAINE","MICHIGAN","MINNESOTA","MISSISSIPPI" )
```

However, when I use:

```
map(database = "state",regions = c,col = "blue",fill=T)
```

It only shows:
[image]

This is not I want, I want to see other states with white color, what should I do?

Comment: `map(database = "state",regions = c,col = c("blue","white"),fill=T)`?

Comment: @user227710 no, it still doesn't work

Comment: do you mean my code doesn't work or the output is not what you are expecting?

Comment: there are examples in the help pages `map(database = "state", col = "blue", fill = FALSE, add = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@rawr solution in comments worked. to create a full map with fill colors:

```
map(database = "state")
map(database = "state",regions = c,col = "blue",fill=T,add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

At the moment you are asking R to only plot those states so you need to drop the `region`-argument and figure out a way to match color choices with the names of the states:

```
require(maps)
namevec <- map(database = "state", col = "blue",fill=T, namesonly=TRUE)

> str(namevec)
 chr [1:63] "alabama" "arizona" "arkansas" "california" ...
```

So try this:

```
map(database = "state",col = c("white", "blue")[1+(namevec %in% tolower(c) )],fill=T)
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I want! Thank you sooooooooo much~